# How to conditionally include views in Blade with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to include some views according to a variable set when defining the view to be rendered.

This is when I render the view:

```
switch (Auth::user()->role) {
      case 'ADMINISTRADOR':
        return View::make('admin');
        break;

      case 'CAPTURISTA':
        return View::make('capturista');
        break;

      case 'GERENTE DE DEPARTAMENTO':
        return View::make('gerente');
        break;

      case 'SUPERVISOR DE COMPRAS':
        return View::make('supervisor', array('supervisor'=>true));
        break;

      case 'GERENTE ADMINISTRATIVO':
        return View::make('administrativo');
        break;
    }
```

So I've tried a lot of things at view in order to load some views **ONLY** if supervisor is true (finally if it was set according to my code).

#### What I've tried

```
@if(isset($supervisor))
  @include('includes.boss.supervisor.delivers_modal')
  @include('includes.boss.supervisor.prices_modal')
  @include('includes.boss.supervisor.providers_modal')
@endif
```

---

```
@if({{isset($supervisor)}})
  @include('includes.boss.supervisor.delivers_modal')
  @include('includes.boss.supervisor.prices_modal')
  @include('includes.boss.supervisor.providers_modal')
@endif
```

---

```
<?php if(isset($message)) : ?>
    @section('message')
        <p>hey all</p>
    @endsection
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

Also I tried setting the `supervisor` variable for every view, naturally to false and true.

```
  @if($supervisor)
          @include('includes.boss.supervisor.delivers_modal')
          @include('includes.boss.supervisor.prices_modal')
          @include('includes.boss.supervisor.providers_modal')
  @endif
```

None of these worked, how should I achieve it?

*** Just in case, I'm using sessions ...**

Comment: https://github.com/romanbican/roles

Comment: you can have all your codes in one blade and separate it by if conditions in blade eg. `@if($user->role == Admin) show this @elseif($user->role == xxx) show this @endif` or if your role packages has spacific blade code you can use them like `@roleadmin show this @endrole`

Answer (score 8):

Since Laravel 5.4 you can use `@includeWhen` .As described in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views):

> ### Including Sub-Views
>
> If you would like to `@include` a view depending on a given boolean
>   condition, you may use the `@includeWhen` directive:
>
> ```
> @includeWhen($boolean, 'view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Why not, instead of showing a specific view, you make a route for each view, then based on the user role, you redirect him to one of the pages?

```
switch (Auth::user()->role) {
   case 'ADMINISTRADOR':
     return redirect('administrador');

   case 'CAPTURISTA':
     return redirect('capturista');
...
```

Then in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('administrador', function() {
   return view('admin');
   // for L4:  View::make('admin');
});

//and one more for each role...
```

If you're using Laravel 4 you need to use the Redirect facade, something like `Redirect::to(..)`;

In your `routes.php` file you would make a route for each view. You can filter the routes to make sure the user has the role it tried to access. More on Laravel 4.2 filters here  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters  and here  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters

For Laravel 5, use middlware to check if the user has permission:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware

Comment: Thanks for your answer, honestly it was a stupid mistake what it was failing. Could you extend your answer with code for every point you mention, in order to make it valuable for someone else?

Comment: I think the routes and the redirect switch is enough. Do you have any idea on what more I can add?

Comment: The answer now has L5 code, with comments for L4 users.